# NodeJS: Handshake Failure: SSL Alert number 40 when doing a http request to AWS Lambda with Axios

Tags: node.js, http, aws-lambda, axios, serverless-framework

I am developing a web application using serverless framework, and in order to use certain services, I need to verify that the user has an active session. To do this, I use a lambda deployed on AWS Lambda that verifies the login and make a call to it in each service using axios in the following way:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
try {
    // Get request headers from the event

    const options = {
        headers: event.headers,
    };


    // Send a request to the verify-user-login endpoint to check if the user is authenticated

    const http = axios.create({ baseURL: "https://**********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/" })

    const responseStatus = await http.get("dev/verify-user-login", options)
        .then(async (response) => {
```

But it fails before doing the request with the next error message:

`AxiosError: write EPROTO 18440:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1546:SSL alert number 40`

When I try to do the same request from postman it works nice. Moreover, when I do the same request from Axios but with the verif-user-login lambda on localhost it works too.

As I understand this error indicates an issue with the SSL/TLS configuration, so I tried to use a custom SSL config as follows:

```
const agent = new https.Agent({
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method', // Use TLSv1.2
  ciphers: 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', // Use multiple cipher suites
});
```

I expected to at least solve the issues with SSL/TLS but I encountered the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error even when trying with fetch and custom agent to disable handshake faillure.
I am using node v18.17.1 ( LTS) and next 13 and this occurs only while using Host header

```
 const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });
 const response = await fetch(myApiURL,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                //headers
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Host': 'myapi.com',
                
            },
            agent: httpsAgent
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue recently. However using either `node:https` or `fetch` the request is completed successfully.